# Sum of reciprocals of $10$ to the power of factorials

Tags: summation, infinity, transcendental-numbers

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^{i!}}$$

I don't remember the name.
Also, if someone would be kind enough to send the proof of its transcendence.
Thanks, envy.

Comment: [Liouville's constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number)?